# Many counts into a join?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I would like to do this query :

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT a.id) as countaid, sum(b.id) as countbid FROM a
INNER JOIN b ON a.id = b.id
WHERE b.otherfield = 0;
```

With 1 count on a :

```
Aclass.joins(:b).where( bclass: {"otherfield" = 0} ).count(:id)
```

And how to do a count distinct ? `count(distinct :id)` ? `count(:id, distinct => true)` ?
Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

In rails 3:

```
Aclass.select("DISTINCT a.id").joins(:b).where( bclass: {otherfield: 0} ).count
```

In rails 4:

```
Aclass.distinct.joins(:b).where( bclass: {otherfield: 0} ).count(:id)
```

Answer (score -1):

You could use `.pluck('DISTINCT id')` or `.collect(&:id).uniq.size`

Comment: I would like to use symbols. like `select([count(distinct(Aclass.table_name.:id), sum(Bclass.table_name.:id)])`

Comment: Don't do this. The performance will be terrible. `collect(&:id)` will return an array of ids which will be counted in Ruby (not SQL). This type of task should be handled by the database.